# Unexpected result return when implementing wait and notify

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, synchronized, notify

I've made a wait and notify example program that is abstraction of a cake shop. there is a thread with role cake machine for producing cake and a thread with role waiter for delivering cake. My expectation is each time the `CakeMachine` class completes producing a cake it will send a notify to the `Waiter` class for delivering. When I run a program which produce 3 cake, the result shows that only one cake is delivered. Here is my code:

The `Cake` class for creating cake object:

```
class Cake {
private int weight;
private String color;

public Cake(int weight, String color) {
    this.weight = weight;
    this.color = color;
    }

public String toString(){
    return "The cake is in " + color  +" and is " + weight + " gram ";

    }
}
```

The `CakeMachine` class for producing cake:

```
class CakeMachine implements Runnable{


private List<Cake> listCake;

CakeMachine(List<Cake> listCake) {
    this.listCake = listCake;
}

public void  makeCake() {
        int weight = new Random().nextInt(20);
        Cake cake = new Cake(weight, "color code is  " + weight );
        listCake.add(cake);
        System.out.println("cake has been cooked ");
        listCake.notify();
}

@Override
public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           synchronized (listCake) {
               makeCake();
           }
        }
    }
}
```

The `Waiter` class for delivering cake:

```
class Waiter implements Runnable {

private List<Cake> listCake;

Waiter(List<Cake> listCake) {
    this.listCake = listCake;
}

public void delivery() {
        System.out.println("Waiter is waiting for the cake ");

            try {
                listCake.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         Cake cake = listCake.get(listCake.size() - 1);
         System.out.println(cake.toString() + "has been delivered to customers ");
}

@Override
public void run() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        synchronized (listCake) {
            delivery();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And the main class:

```
public class WaitAndNotify {

    public static List<Cake> listCake = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Thread waiter = new Thread(new Waiter(listCake));
    Thread cakeMachine = new Thread(new CakeMachine(listCake));
    waiter.start();
    cakeMachine.start();

    }
}
```

The result when run the program is:

```
Waiter is waiting for the cake 
cake has been cooked 
cake has been cooked 
cake has been cooked 
The cake is in color code is  18 and is 18 gram has been delivered to   customers 
Waiter is waiting for the cake
```

Please help me to understand this situation.

Comment: [Effective Java Item 69](https://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA273&ots=yZHnPev1T4&dq=effective%20java%20wait%20notify&pg=PA273#v=onepage&q=effective%20java%20wait%20notify&f=false): "*There is seldom, if ever, a reason to use `wait` and `notify` in new code.*"

Comment: You should use Queue instead of List, and use ConcurrentLinkedQueue from concurrent package to ignore multi threading problem.

Comment: Notified thread(Waiter in this case) does not automatically reacquire the lock on notify. Both Waiter and CakeMachine threads must compete for the lock after notify and in your case CakeMachine gets the lock.

Answer (score 2):

Two major points:

- You don't have control over which thread runs when.
- notify has no effect if no other thread happens to be waiting on that monitor. Your waiter stops waiting and the cake-making is free to proceed, and finishes before the waiter acquires the monitor again.

In your example the scheduler decides to run one iteration of your waiter first, then runs all 3 iterations of cake-making, then runs the next two iterations of waiting, after all the cakes have been made. You could introduce flags to indicate when a cake was prepared and when a waiter was waiting, and make the cake-making delay notifying until a waiter was present, but it's really a mistake to try to get threads to execute in lockstep, it defeats the purpose of separating activities into their own threads.

With the condition flags added the delivery method would look something like:

```
public void delivery() {
    System.out.println("Waiter is waiting for the cake ");
    waiterInPosition = true;
    try {
        while (!(cakeQueued)) {
            listCake.wait();
        }
        waiterInPosition = false;
        cakeQueued = false;
        Cake cake = listCake.get(listCake.size() - 1);
        System.out.println(cake.toString() 
        + "has been delivered to customers ");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); // restore interrupt flag
    }
}
```

But this is a toy example and it is very awkward. It would be more natural to model this as a producer-consumer problem where the cake-maker added cakes to a queue and the waiter took cakes off the queue. You can try making your own blocking queue, your queue methods can handle the waiting and notifying -- it's a lot more natural to have your data structure handle synchronization and blocking than it is to make the worker tasks do it. That will teach you as much about using wait and notify as your current example, while being more representative of real-world concurrency patterns.

The [Oracle tutorial on guarded blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) includes a blocking queue example, and the advice about waiting in a loop with a condition variable is essential, go read it.

Comment: I really don't understand why 3 iterations of cake-making are run continuously. Because every time the notify() method is called, it should wake up a "Waiter" thread, and the delivery() method should be executed. Can you explain it in more details. Thanks.

Comment: @programer310: hope added explanation helps

Comment: At a second major point, you said that the waiter stops waiting and the cake-making is free to proceed. But how can the waiter stops waiting. They said that when a wait() is called, the thread will wait infinitely until it receives an notify() from other thread, won't it?

Comment: @programer310: yes, if you have your thread wait without a timeout and nothing ever notifies it it can continue waiting indefinitely.

Comment: Ok so finally, in my case the unexpected result appears because three notify() method were called before the wait() actually present, doesn't it?

Comment: @programer310: that can happen. that's a reason to use the loop and condition variable as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with Typical producer consumer problem

The Cake Class:

```
class Cake {
private int weight;
private String color;

public Cake(int weight, String color) {
    this.weight = weight;
    this.color = color;
}

public String toString() {
    return "The cake is in " + color + " and is " + weight + " gram ";

}
}
```

CakeMachine acts as both producer and consumer that is it has both delivercake and make cake function

```
class CakeMachine {

private LinkedList<Cake> listCake = new LinkedList<Cake>();;
private Random random = new Random();
private static int LIMIT = 5;

public void makeCake() throws InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
        synchronized (this) {
            while (listCake.size() == LIMIT) {
                wait();
            }
            int weight = random.nextInt(20);
            Cake cake = new Cake(weight, "color code is  " + weight);
            listCake.add(cake);
            System.out.println("cake has been cooked ");
            notify();
        }
    }
}

public void deliverCake() throws InterruptedException {
    while (true) {
        synchronized (this) {
            Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000)); // on average 500 ms
            while (listCake.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println("Waiter is waiting for the cake ");
                wait();
            }

            Cake cake = listCake.removeFirst();
            System.out.println(cake.toString() + "has been delivered to customers ");
            notify();
        }
    }
}

}
```

Now the final and main class

```
public class CakeThreading {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final CakeMachine cm = new CakeMachine();
    Thread cakeproducer = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                cm.makeCake();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    Thread waiter = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                cm.deliverCake();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    cakeproducer.start();
    waiter.start();

    try {
        cakeproducer.join();
        waiter.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

This will produce an output like this:

```
cake has been cooked 
cake has been cooked 
The cake is in color code is  2 and is 2 gram has been delivered to customers 
The cake is in color code is  14 and is 14 gram has been delivered to customers 
cake has been cooked 
cake has been cooked 
cake has been cooked 
The cake is in color code is  13 and is 13 gram has been delivered to customers 
The cake is in color code is  7 and is 7 gram has been delivered to customers 
The cake is in color code is  19 and is 19 gram has been delivered to customers 
Waiter is waiting for the cake 
cake has been cooked 
cake has been cooked 
cake has been cooked 
The cake is in color code is  12 and is 12 gram has been delivered to customers 
The cake is in color code is  2 and is 2 gram has been delivered to customers 
The cake is in color code is  2 and is 2 gram has been delivered to customers 
cake has been cooked 
cake has been cooked
```